# Making span to take up all space and centered horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I made a calendar using table, HTML of which goes as follows:

```
[...]
<tr>
    <td><span id = "0">00</span></td>
    <td><span id = "1">01</span></td>
    <td><span id = "2">02</span></td>
    <td><span id = "3">03</span></td>
    <td><span id = "4">04</span></td>
    <td><span id = "5">05</span></td>
    <td><span id = "6">06</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id = "7">07</span></td>
    <td><span id = "8">08</span></td>
    <td><span id = "9">09</span></td>
    <td><span id = "10">10</span></td>
    <td><span id = "11">11</span></td>
    <td><span id = "12">12</span></td>
    <td><span id = "13">13</span></td>
</tr>
[...]
```

Now, the main point is, I want to give hovering effect on my span elements.For that I need span to take up all space of parent td and be centered horizontally and vertically. I did some googling, but nothing seems to work.I hope I made my situation clear. How to make span take up all space of td so that hovering produces desired effect, or should I use div instead of span(if that may ease my way), or there exists anyother workaround to produce hovering effect.

Thanks in advance!!

CSS:

```
 .cal1 .clndr span {
     color: #3a3b36;
     font-size: 15px;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 td {
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: 1px solid black;
     text-align: center;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: why don't you give background color to TD, and change it on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inherit the `height` from the `td` element and set the spans `display` property to `block`, adding `line-height` as well will take care of vertical centering.

Here is an example

```css
td {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td span {
  color: #3a3b36;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: 64px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

td span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id = "0">00</span></td>
    <td><span id = "1">01</span></td>
    <td><span id = "2">02</span></td>
    <td><span id = "3">03</span></td>
    <td><span id = "4">04</span></td>
    <td><span id = "5">05</span></td>
    <td><span id = "6">06</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><span id = "7">07</span></td>
    <td><span id = "8">08</span></td>
    <td><span id = "9">09</span></td>
    <td><span id = "10">10</span></td>
    <td><span id = "11">11</span></td>
    <td><span id = "12">12</span></td>
    <td><span id = "13">13</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Deepak suggested in the comments, why not do away with the spans and use the tds instead?

As such...

```
<tr>
    <td>00</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
    <td>04</td>
    <td>05</td>
    <td>06</td>
</tr>
```

Then style them:

```
td:hover {
    background: #f00;
}
```

---

As for why they won't fill, spans are, by default AND your declaration (`display:inline-block;`) inline elements. Divs are block-level elements so you are correct in asking if this is more appropriate.
Therefore you can either change the css to `display: block;` or use divs.

This would then be styled with `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%` to achieve your desired effect.

**Edit:**

Sorry, spans are `display:inline;` by default. Your declaration of `display:inline-block` already does the same as `display:block` in this situation. Regardless of whether `display:inline-block` or `display:block` is used, vertical-align won't work (see http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) so either omit the span elements like I said or refer to DavidDomain's answer if you're okay with your cells being fixed-size.